# Problem with element jumping up and down between reloads (header with float: right;)

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem with an element in a web page.  When I load the page the header is usually on top:
[image]

... and when I reload the elements goes down to the next box:

[image]

When I press reload few times it jumps up and down randomly between reloads.

This seems to only happen in Chrome (I'm using mac) but in Firefox the element is always on top like in the first example.  I don't have much experience with html and css so I'm not sure how to track the error.

I'm using Blueprint css and I place the element in css like this:

nav {
  float: right;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 0.7em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

The example can bee seen here:  http://foodoit.heroku.com/help

Hope somebody has an idea what is causing this or how I would go about tracking the error.

Update:  I fixed the rails.js as described below but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: removed tag `rails` because this is a css html problem

Answer (score 0):

rails.js has an error in the start. You use doctype declaration in this file which in fact is a html file will `<script>` tags inside it. Fix this and check it.

Comment: rails.js is a JQuery file which I got from the library and haven't changed myself.  Are you talking about changing that file?

This is the beginning of that file:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: but a javascript file can't stat in this way. Doctype is a declaration of html file. If you check your browser you will see that it gives error from this file

Comment: Ok, the rails.js was invalid and I have fixed that.  However the jumping up and down between reloads descriped in my original post is still a problem.  Any other ideas?